# Changing the appearance of collection of items according to a single property in XAML

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, triggers

I have 4 buttons in grid which datacontext is set to an object which has property that indicates what button should be enabled (it's enumerable).

Currenty I have done this in code-behind so that when that specific property changes, it disables all but one depending on the value. It works, but I really don't like to put stuff like this to code-behind. There must be a way to do this in xaml?

I could make own style for all four buttons and then do this with data triggers, but I would prefer more generic approach: use same style for all buttons that somehow applies differently depending on, for example, a button name and value of the property.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a MultiBinding to bind the IsEnabled property to a combination of the control's name and the property from your DataContext, and create a Style to apply it to all buttons in the Grid:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <local:EqualsConverter x:Key="EqualsConverter"/>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualsConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Name"/>
                    <Binding Path="EnabledButtonName"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

And in code:

```
public class EqualsConverter
    : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Length == 2 && object.Equals(values[0], values[1]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an association between the `enum` you've created and the buttons by having integer references to your enum values and giving those enum values as [ConverterParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter.aspx) for corresponding buttons.

For Eg:

**The enum:**

```
public enum myOptions
{
    value1 = 1,
    value2 = 2,
    value3 = 3,
    value4 = 4
}
```

**The Binding:**

```
<Button IsEnabled = {Binding Path=myProperty, 
                             Converter = {StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, 
                             ConverterParameter = 1} />
<Button IsEnabled = {Binding Path=myProperty, 
                             Converter = {StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, 
                             ConverterParameter = 2} />
```

**And the Converter:**

```
public class EnumToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value == (int)parameter;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```